# Read error with Json file

Tags: android, json

I am working on an app in **Android Studio** that downloads a **json file from a php query**, however when I have managed to read the contents of the json file from android, this contents does not behave as text, because when comparing a text entered from the app against the read from the json file, it never matches despite being the same text. (Example: password text from app and the password from the json file).

**Php Code:**

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include('functions.php');
$col=$_GET["col"];
$colbus=$_GET["colbus"];
$tabla=$_GET["nomtable"];
$todfilas=$_GET["todasf"];
$dbuser =$_GET["username"];
$dbpass=$_GET["password"];
$dbbase=$_GET["dbname"];

//echo "$todfilas <br>";

if($todfilas == 1){
    $sqlt="SELECT * FROM $tabla";
}else{
    $sqlt="SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $col='$colbus'";
    }
//echo "$sqlt <br>";

if($resultset=getSQLResultSet($sqlt,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbbase)){
    while ($row = $resultset->mysqli_fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
        echo json_encode($row);
    }
}

?>
```

**Code from Android Studio:**

```
private class ConsultData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            try {
                return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "No es posible cargar pagina web o la direccion es invalida!";
            }
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            JSONArray ja = null;
            try {
                ja = new JSONArray(result);
                Log.d("Password:",ja.getString(7)+"="+logPass.getText().toString().trim());

                logPass2.setText(ja.getString(7).trim());

                String pass1 =logPass2.toString();

                String pass0 = logPass.toString().trim();

                if(pass0==pass1){
                    showAlertDialog("Session:","login is valid!");
                } else{
                    showAlertDialog("Session:","password does not match!");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if **the way to create the json file in the php query is the problem**? because I can see the contents of the json array in Android Studio, but when I compare text from json array, they do not match even if they are the same ("123" = "123").

Comment: you can not compare string like that use equals to compare string.

Comment: Can you show Logcat?

Comment: @Bunny thank you i’ll try that.

Comment: i have mentioned your mistakes below  in ans see and rectify those mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seeing your code you doing so many mistakes like you are getting textview value thats not right way

change code like this

```
String pass1 =logPass2.getText().toString();

      String pass0 = logPass.getText().toString().trim();
```

Also comparsion of string

```
 if(pass0.equals(pass1)){
                    showAlertDialog("Session:","login is valid!");
                } else{
                    showAlertDialog("Session:","password does not match!");
                }
```

instead of this

```
 if(pass0==pass1){
                    showAlertDialog("Session:","login is valid!");
                } else{
                    showAlertDialog("Session:","password does not match!");
                }
```